# Make a curl request to a url having no file extension?

Tags: php, curl

I have following URL

http://www.davesinclairstpeters.com/auto2_inventorylist?i=37647&c=12452&npg=1&ns=50&echo=2

I want to retrieve content of this url using curl but everytime I make this request it is showing me error, as it is not passing required parameters

Below is my code

```
    $ch = curl_init(); // start CURL
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $json_url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);      
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: There is no error actually, it is just not passing required get parameters, otherwise url is working fine via browser

Comment: "but everytime I make this request it is showing me error"

Comment: If it's not working, it means there's an error of some sort. How do you know it's not passing required parameters, and if something told you, then paste exactly what it said in your original post.

Comment: sorry it is just a sample url, actual url is http://www.davesinclairstpeters.com/auto2_inventorylist?i=37647&c=12452&npg=1&ns=50&echo=2

Comment: @user1217774 That actual page is an error page...

Comment: @user1217774 I see an error too in the page.

Answer (score 3):

That page doesn't give any information stating that the information isn't being passed properly. In fact, it tells you that the information *has* been recieved - by viewing the source, you can see:

```
<!--
javax.servlet.forward.request_uri = /auto2_inventorylist
...
javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path = /auto2_inventorylist
...
javax.servlet.forward.query_string = i=37647&c=12452&npg=1&ns=50&echo=2
-->
```

Which tells you the information has infact been recieved.

Therefore, it's no problem with your code, but with the website itself. You should make sure the URL you are using is valid, or contact that website to get more information.

With regards to your code itself - the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);` isn't necessary, as this is already set by default, and you can also pass the URL as an argument of the `curl_init` function. Doesn't impact performance, but makes for neater code.

```
$ch = curl_init($json_url); // start CURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);      
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

You code is perfectly fine and if there's something wrong returned, simply paste this URL to your web browser and check the result. In this case website simply failed for some reasons. There's nothing you can do about that as problem is **NOT** on your side.

Answer (score 0):

This URL yields a page of cars with links to more cars.  Looks like the URL you're starting with is old, or has some sort of expiration factor that's not obvious.

Not knowing which sort of filtering parameters you're shooting for.. hard to say what else my be wrong, other than your starting URL be bad.

working url:

```
http://www.davesinclairlincolnstpeters.com/all-inventory/index.htm?listingConfigId=auto-new%2Cauto-used&compositeType=&year=&make=&start=0&sort=&facetbrowse=true&quick=true&preserveSelectsOnBack=true&searchLinkText=SEARCH&showInvTotals=false&showRadius=false&showReset=true&showSubmit=true&facetbrowseGridUnit=BLANK&showSelections=true&dependencies=model%3Amake%2Ccity%3Aprovince%2Ccity%3Astate&suppressAllConditions=false
```

Comment: Wow.. OK, so why did this show up on the top of the feed for relevant questions.. it's like 5 years old..     talk about a blast from the past...